# How to wait till call to a web service is completed?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am trying to get the FedAuth Cookie from a web service. But what is happening is that before I get the result from the web service, the other method `GetFedAuthCookieFromSOAPResponse` method is getting executed and the parameter passed to it is becoming `null` . Hence I am getting the exception:

startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex

How do I wait till I get the soap response from the web service and then excute the method `GetFedAuthCookieFromSOAPResponse` ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://server/site";
            string soapResponse = GetSOAPResponse(url, "http://site/server/exapmle.asmx");
            Console.WriteLine(GetFedAuthCookieFromSOAPResponse(soapResponse));
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close program");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        internal static string GetSOAPResponse(string url, string serviceURL)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><GetFedAuthCookie xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><requestUrl>" + url + "</requestUrl><userName></userName><password></password></GetFedAuthCookie></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetFedAuthCookie");
                string soapResult = string.Empty;
                client.UploadString(new Uri(serviceURL), request);
                client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
                    soapResult = e.Result;
                });                
                return soapResult;
            }
        }
        internal static string GetFedAuthCookieFromSOAPResponse(string soapResponse)
        {
            string openingTag = "<GetFedAuthCookieResult>";
            string closingTag = "</GetFedAuthCookieResult>";
            int startIndex = soapResponse.IndexOf(openingTag) + openingTag.Length;
            int length = soapResponse.IndexOf(closingTag) - startIndex;
            return soapResponse.Substring(startIndex, length);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UploadString` is already a synchronous method. Meaning that when the method returns the operation has completed. `UploadStringCompleted` is used only when dealing with asynchronous methods like `UploadStringAsync` or `UploadStringTaskAsync`.

`UploadString` returns a string which is the response from server.

You simply need

```
string soapResult = client.UploadString(new Uri(serviceURL), request);
return soapResult;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is where you respond to the completion of the web service request:

```
client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    soapResult = e.Result;
});
```

So you can perform your follow-up logic there:

```
client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetFedAuthCookieFromSOAPResponse(e.Result));
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close program");
    Console.ReadLine();
});
```

Or you could refactor that logic out into a method and call that method from in there, etc.

But essentially since this is an asynchronous operation, you don't "wait until it's completed" but instead you "respond to its completion event".

Comment: I want to wait till the call completes. There are other methods which uses the return value of the method 'GetFedAuthCookieFromSOAPResponse'

Comment: @Karthik: Anything which uses the value returned by an asynchronous operation would need to be invoked by the response handler for that operation.  Now, if there's a *synchronous* method call which the web service proxy exposes, that would be another story entirely.

Comment: @Karthik: Upon further inspection, it looks like the call actually is synchronous.  The other answer on this question will likely prove simpler.